# Send only event body to lambda not whole event, when message gets added to SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have configured SQS as event source for lambda. When message gets published in SQS it invokes the lambda and send following JSON as event -

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "messageId": "11d6ee51-4cc7-4302-9e22-7cd8afdaadf5",
            "receiptHandle": "AQEBBX8nesZEXmkhsmZeyIE8iQAMig7qw...",
            "body": " { Test message. }",
            "attributes": {
                "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
                "SentTimestamp": "1573251510774",
                "SequenceNumber": "18849496460467696128",
                "MessageGroupId": "1",
                "SenderId": "AIDAIO23YVJENQZJOL4VO",
                "MessageDeduplicationId": "1",
                "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1573251510774"
            },
            "messageAttributes": {},
            "md5OfBody": "e4e68fb7bd0e697a0ae8f1bb342846b3",
            "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
            "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:123456789012:fifo.fifo",
            "awsRegion": "us-east-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

but I want that only following event should be sent -

```
{ Test message. }
```

that is basically *body* of the message.

P.S.- Lambda is invoked from other sources also, so I can't change the message request format in my code.

Comment: You might need to create another lambda function to read from SQS and post on the lambda which needs only { Test message. } via the API gateway

Comment: Which language do you use for lambda? There should be some frameworks to help parse event messages in lambda.

Comment: @SangminKim I am using Java